# Is an OAuth refresh token a valid / secure alternative for a mobile device identifier

Tags: mobile, oauth, oauth-2.0

Asking as a relative n00b on mobile applications here as I'm primarily a backend developer.

We are building a mobile app and have a business requirement for users' devices to be uniquely identified and registered with the backend (i.e. users can install app but to access services they need to register that device with our backend services and there is a limit of X devices that can be registered simultaneously).

The front end team currently have created a function to extract a unique device ID from the mobile device but we were also told by the security team that device IDs are considered sensitive information and we should not be transmitting this information over the wire.

Putting aside that encryption can be applied to the device ID, I was mulling about alternatives to the device ID altogether. We are using OAuth for authentication and at the end of a valid registration, an OAuth access and refresh token is generated. Since the refresh token is supposed to be long-lived and is stored securely (assumed) client-side, can the refresh token be used as a replacement for the device ID? Would there be any known holes in this strategy? Refresh tokens are supposed to be "long-lived" per the documentation, but how long-lived exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the life span of the Oauth2 tokens, But this will defeat the purpose of Oauth2. If the device is compromised, What are you going to do about it. You will have to invalidate the tokens.

Using the device ID is the way to go, if it is universally unique or you are sure that there will be no conflicts.

I suggest you to use the device ID and leave the Oauth2 default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You should use SHA256 to hash the Device ID.  OAuth tokens are volatile, even refresh tokens at some point.